# Camel route with MyBatis delivers ArrayList of HashMaps instead of HashMap

Tags: hashmap, apache-camel, mybatis

Using MyBatis in a Camel route to select key/value pairs from a database table I got the following issue.

My route (as a part of a content enricher):

```
from("direct:resource")
   .setBody().constant(123)
   .to("mybatis:selectParameters?statementType=SelectList")
   ...;
```

Mapper:

```
<select id="selectParameters" parameterType="int" resultType="java.util.HashMap">
   SELECT 
      KEY
     ,VALUE
   FROM 
      TABLE
   WHERE 
      ID=#{id}
</select>
```

Everything works fine except that the body contains an ArrayList of HashMaps (one for each key/value pair) instead of one HashMap with n k/v pairs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you should use statementType=SelectOne as you only select one row in the SQL query. Because you use SelectList then a List is always returned, even if there is only 1 row from the SQL resultset.

You can see which statement types is possible here: http://camel.apache.org/mybatis

And of course consult the MyBatis documentation for further details on using MyBatis etc.

Comment: Probably the where condition is missleading: I select n rows (n > 1) therefore SelectList should be correct. Im not quite sure if the use of a hashmap is possible in mybatis the way im trying to. I have a List<HashMap> with 4 list entries, each a HashMap with 1 key/value pair. It works but it feels very wrong.